# Angular cached, multicast observable, don't make HTTP call until subscribed

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that exposes some global state using an observable. The state must be initialized by making an HTTP call. I want all consumers of the state to receive the same value, receive the current value when they subscribe to the observable, and receive updates when the state changes.

This scenario is typically handled using a `Subject`, which can be initialized by subscribing it to the observable returned by the HTTP request.

However, I don't want the HTTP request to be executed until the first time something subscribes to the global state observable. If you use the `subscribe` method of the `Subject`, the HTTP request is called then.

I have the following code in the service. This works, but it seems like there should be a simpler way to do this.

```
  private initialized = false;
  private readonly subject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  get data$(): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable<string>(subscriber => {
      if (!this.initialized) {
        this.refresh();
      }
      let subscription = this.subject.subscribe(value => subscriber.next(value));
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  refresh(): void {
    this.httpClient.get<string>('https://...')
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.initialized = true)
      )
      .subscribe(value => this.subject.next(value));
  }
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-almeida-d2zbjx?file=/src/app/test.service.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should accomplish what you want.  The *data$* field should be the merge of two observables.  The first will be the initial http call and the other will be listening to emission from *refreshSubject* to call the service again.

The initial call won't execute until the first subscription is made and any call to *refreshSubject* will be ignored as well.

Finally, using *shareReplay* will cause all subsequent subscribers to get the last result.  The *refCount* parameter is used so that if subscriber count becomes zero, the subscription is completely unsubscribed, and the next subscriber will initiate the first call again.  If this behavior is not desirable, you can just use `shareReplay(1)` which will always have the last result and continue to listen to *refreshSubject*.

```
readonly refreshSubject = new subject<void>();
readonly data$ = merge(
  this.httpClient.get<string>('https://...'),
  this.refreshSubject.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get<string>('https://...'))
  )
).pipe(
  shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1, refCount: true })
);
```

Comment: You know, I had tried `shareReplay` before, but couldn't figure out the update/refresh aspect. Based on this technique I was able to DRY the solution somewhat, which I'll include as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the subscribe and unsubscribe in your `data$()` method is doing. Does this simpler version (returning `subject.asObservable()`) also meet your requirements?

```
get data$(): Observable<string> {
  if (!this.initialized) {
    this.refresh();
  }
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: I had a version like this at one point. The problem with this is that it will invoke the HTTP request when the `data$` property is referenced, before `subscribe` is called.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in similar situations is to create a service that works like this.

1. It exposes methods to fire the execution of commands, e.g. execute the http call
2. It exposes Observables to which clients can subscribe when they want to react to changes
3. Internally uses Subjects to trigger the notifications in the public Observables when the execution of the commands returns something (or errors)

So, in code, it would look something like this

```
export class MyService {
  private _subject = new ReplySubject<any>(1);
  public data$ = this._subject.asObservable();

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public executeRemoteService(inputParams: any) {
     // the request is executed as soon as a client calls this method
     // the subject notifies, errors and completes mirroring what the 
     // http client does
     this.httpClient.get<string>('https://...')
      .pipe(
         tap(this.data$)
      )
      .subscribe()
  }  
}
```

Any client interested in `data$`, i.e. interested in changes in the global state, has to subscribe to `data$` and this can happen in any moment.

When is the moment to fire the execution of the service, any component can call the execution of the `executeRemoteService` method which will then triggers the notifications in `data$`.

Comment: I have some services constructed like this, mostly for data that is initialized using resolvers. In the new code I'm trying to eliminate the need for the separate call to something like `executeRemoteService` to hydrate the observable. The observable is referenced using an `async` pipe and is hidden behind an `*ngIf`, so it won't be subscribed unless the user shows that part of the page.

Comment: I prefer a model where services expose "method" APIs, to allow clients execute commands, and "Observable" APIs, to allow clients to react to changes. In my opinion this structure divides clearly the "imperative" code (where I issue commands) from the "reactive declarative" code, where I react to changes. It is the model of the "store" (e.g. Rudux, NgRx). It is not mathematics though and, at the end of the day, it is a matter of taste and what someone feels easier to follow and reason about.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @DanielGimenez, I implemented the solution below. It has the advantage of being slightly simpler and more DRY.

```
private readonly refreshSubject = new BehaviorSubject<void>(void 0);

constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {
  this.data$ = this.refreshSubject
    .pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get<string>('https://...')),
        shareReplay(1)
    );
}

readonly data$: Observable<string>;

refresh(): void {
  this.refreshSubject.next();
}
```