# Angular: Should service produced data get passed from parent to child?

Tags: angular, typescript

My question is more theoritical rather than practise becaue I already have something working well but there is something makes me feel like something is not quite right with it, and I couldn't find any related topic to this in internet.

Let say we have a parent component, called: `ParentComponent.ts`

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 protected someData: string | null = null

 constructor(
  protected dataService: DataService,
 ) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getSomedata();
  
  this.dataService.dataGenerated.pipe(skip(1).subscribe(data => {
   this.somedata = data
  });
 }

}
```

Then let say I have two children component that need this `someData` for their own use, let's call them: `ChildOneComponent.ts` and `ChildTwoComponent.ts`

Imagine both component looks like this on their base:

```
export class ChildOneComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 @Input() data: string | null = null
}
```

what I do is, in my parent component template:

```
<app-child-one [data]="someData"></app-child-one>
<app-child-two [data]="someData"></app-child-two>
```

My question is this: Is `someData` should get passed this way to the usage of child component from parent or should children also `subscribe` the `this.dataservice.dataGenerated` and use it from there, then have no `@Input()` fields?

What is the best implementation and why?

Comment: As with anything, it depends. How "smart" are the children? Do they own the data too or do they just display it? Can the children change the data or should they consider it immutable? Do the children need to coordinate with each other on the data? I don't think you'll get a satisfactory "canon" answer because there are situations where both approaches are desirable (and some where neither is).

Comment: Opinion-based question. Short answer - depends... on your business requirements. Besides that - what is easier, what takes less memory (if service returns new reference with new data to each consumer), what takes less code to write - passing data via attributes data binding or injecting service, adding onInit and onDestroy to subscribe and unsubscribe from service obs method? Any guarantees that this method will return same data to parent and child component? What is the reason to have this data in parent if it is used in childs only? So it all depends...

Comment: As others said, it depends. But if the data comes from a backend request, then passing it to children is better than having them fetch it again.

Comment: Ok let me elaborate this a bit more for you guys. The `this.dataService.getSomedata()` method is an API request to back-end and it updates the value of `this.dataService.dataGenerated`. So @ekalin my children actually does not re-fetch data, but then are consuming the data fetched from remote one way another. I kind of want to stick to a certain implementation to create some consistency in my code-base, so I will know that data is passed from parent everytime or used from `DataService`.

Comment: So basically child components are `useless` without someone at parent level calling `getSomedata`. So in one way your child components are depending on data from parent via databinding, in another way they are depending on parent component calling data fetching function, depending on service, subscribind and unsubscribing. Sounds like spaghetti code to me.

Comment: @SergeySosunov yeah since there are more than 1 child then it would be a bit of overkill to handover the API call to children and let them call the API each one, then there would be # of children amount of call to API. This way I tried to avoid the API call to get called only once and children to consume the result. Do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: Well you can check caching, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72116564/angular-cached-multicast-observable-dont-make-http-call-until-subscribed). It is a bit more complicated rxjs topic but it can help you achieve what you want.